# Is this Calendly.com URL Valid?

Tags: url, curl, webhooks, calendly

I am using webhooks for the first time with [calendly.com](http://calendly.com). I would like to create a subscription as described [here](http://developer.calendly.com/docs/webhook-subscriptions). When I get to doing this

```
curl --header "X-TOKEN: <your_token>" --data "url=https://blah.foo/bar&events[]=invitee.created" https://calendly.com/api/v1/hooks
```

I am concerned that the `url` is not in a valid format. I tried replacing the `&` with a `?` as in here

```
curl --header "X-TOKEN: <your_token>" --data "url=https://blah.foo/bar?events[]=invitee.created" https://calendly.com/api/v1/hooks
```

but I receive this error

```
{"events":{"events":["can't be blank]}}
```

Likewise, I try to leave the `&` and everything after it blank and it give the same error as above.

But using a url with the `&` and everything in it gives a 404 not found error. Can a url even have the format they are saying is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But using a url with the `&` and everything in it gives a 404 not found error.

The URL part in the following is just the `https://blah.foo/bar` part before the `&` character.

```
curl --header "X-TOKEN: <your_token>" --data "url=https://blah.foo/bar&events[]=invitee.created" https://calendly.com/api/v1/hooks
```

The `events[]=invitee.created` part is a separate parameter and value. It’s not part of the `url`.

See the [Create A Webhook Subscription](http://developer.calendly.com/docs/webhook-subscriptions) page in the calendy docs:

[image: calendly documentation]

So the URL is the site that runs your webhook; you don’t send the `events` parameter/value back to that site—instead you’re sending both the `url` param and `events` param to the calendly API endpoint at `https://calendly.com/api/v1/hooks`. The calendly backend presumably then calls to `https://mywebsite.com/webhooks/invitee_created` or `https://blah.foo/bar` whatever `url` you’ve given it—but without the `events` parameter, which is for calendly’s internal use.

Comment: Thank you. You are exactly correct. I was thinking the events was part of a query parameter list, but it's for the folks at calendly, not me. Thanks for this detailed answer.